# Why don't Decals line up correctly in Rocket League Garage Inventory?

Tags: rocket-league

I've asked around and no one seems to know the answer to this.

Here we have 3 types of very rare snakeskin decals. 
Breakout, X-Devil & Dominus. There doesn't seem to be any order or predictable structure to the way it's organized.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? 
Is it possible to fix?

Comment: Looks like a bug

Comment: Possibly its just the way they made the game?

Comment: Might be in the order you received them?